# How to prevent a draggable div from overlapping another in native javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to restrict a draggable div from overlapping another div. How do i do this wth native javascript? No jquery/ui. Any tutorials/examples??

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping"? Do you mean you want to prevent it from _dropping_ on that another `DIV`, or do you want to make it top-most so it won't get covered?

Comment: i want to prevent it from dropping on to another DIV.

Comment: You can listen to `ondragenter` and `ondragover` on that another `DIV`, and set `event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed="none"` and `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect="none"`. [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#Drag_Effects)